# JSONDecoder decode same fromat different type

Tags: ios, json

I'm using JSONDecoder to parse my JSON response:

```
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":1}
```

or

```
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":"a"}
```

or

```
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":{"name":"a"}}
```

or

```
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":{"text":"b"}}
```

or

```
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":[{"name":"a"}]}
```

Here is my basejson

```
import Foundation

class BaseJson: Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var status: String
    var errorCode: String
    var msg: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status", errorCode = "errorCode", msg = "msg", info = "info"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .status) ?? "0"
        errorCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .errorCode) ?? "0"
        msg = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .msg) ?? "1"
    }
}
```

So what should I do to make this basic class parse all the results

Comment: What do you want for `info` to be? Stop thinking with Codable and how to decode it, just how would you want it in your `struct`? It could be enum holding possible cases String, Array, Dictionary?

Comment: If it's **your** JSON response send consistent data. This is more efficient than a multiple type check at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Enum with associated value to handle that.

But as said by vadian, if you can, it's better that the API responds always the same kind of data according to the same parameters.

You can add this:

```
enum Info: Decodable {

    enum DecodingError: Error {
        case unknownValueType
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let asInt = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .intValue(asInt)
        } else if let asString = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .stringValue(asString)
        } else if let asDict = try? container.decode([String: String].self) {
            self = .dictValue(asDict)
        } else if let asArrayofDicts = try? container.decode([[String: String]].self) {
            self = .arrayOfDictValue(asArrayofDicts)
        } else {
            throw Info.DecodingError.unknownValueType
        }
    }

    case intValue(Int)
    case stringValue(String)
    case dictValue([String: String])
    case arrayOfDictValue([[String: String]])
}
```

I used `[String: String]` and `[[String: String]]`, but if that's limited you can also put your own custom struct:

struct InfoText: Decodable {
let text: String
}

struct InfoName: Decodable {
let name: String
}

and do:

case infoText(InfoText)

if let asInfoText = try? container.decode(InfoText.self) { ... }

etc.

Full code and text (copy pastable in Plyagrounds):

```
class BaseJson: Decodable {

    enum Info: Decodable {

        enum DecodingError: Error {
            case unknownValueType
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let asInt = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
                self = .intValue(asInt)
            } else if let asString = try? container.decode(String.self) {
                self = .stringValue(asString)
            } else if let asDict = try? container.decode([String: String].self) {
                self = .dictValue(asDict)
            } else if let asArrayofDicts = try? container.decode([[String: String]].self) {
                self = .arrayOfDictValue(asArrayofDicts)
            } else {
                throw Info.DecodingError.unknownValueType
            }
        }

        case intValue(Int)
        case stringValue(String)
        case dictValue([String: String])
        case arrayOfDictValue([[String: String]])
    }

    var id = UUID()
    var status: String
    var errorCode: String
    var msg: String
    var info: Info

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status", errorCode = "errorCode", msg = "msg", info = "info"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .status)
        errorCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .errorCode)
        msg = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .msg)
        info = try container.decode(Info.self, forKey: .info)
    }

    static func test() {
        let jsonStr = """
[
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":1},
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":"a"},
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":{"name":"a"}},
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":{"text":"b"}},
{"status":"1","errorCode":"0","msg":"","info":[{"name":"a"}]}
]
"""

        let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            let bases = try JSONDecoder().decode([BaseJson].self, from: jsonData)
            print(bases)

            for aBase in bases {
                var infoStr = ""
                switch aBase.info {
                case .arrayOfDictValue(let array):
                    infoStr = "\(array)"
                case .dictValue(let dictt):
                    infoStr = "\(dictt)"
                case .intValue(let intV):
                    infoStr = "\(intV)"
                case .stringValue(let str):
                    infoStr = str
                }
                print("Got: \(aBase.id), status: \(aBase.status), errorCode: \(aBase.errorCode), msg: \(aBase.msg), info: \(aBase.info) - badStringConversion for understanding: \(infoStr)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

BaseJson.test()
```

Output:

```
$> [__lldb_expr_75.BaseJson, __lldb_expr_75.BaseJson, __lldb_expr_75.BaseJson, __lldb_expr_75.BaseJson, __lldb_expr_75.BaseJson]
$> Got: C92A4315-413C-4DA3-9D0B-E6CE3B081AF3, status: 1, errorCode: 0, msg: , info: intValue(1) - badStringConversion for understanding: 1
$> Got: 1AB9FE74-E282-4AC9-97B1-814DD5C9F412, status: 1, errorCode: 0, msg: , info: stringValue("a") - badStringConversion for understanding: a
$> Got: F082FD0D-818D-4A6F-906A-3A80D911C2BA, status: 1, errorCode: 0, msg: , info: dictValue(["name": "a"]) - badStringConversion for understanding: ["name": "a"]
$> Got: 2424AFD2-8417-4FCB-B97A-D03AB30A9C45, status: 1, errorCode: 0, msg: , info: dictValue(["text": "b"]) - badStringConversion for understanding: ["text": "b"]
$> Got: 05DDB7CB-DD0E-41BB-B878-F1AEBF0D6F43, status: 1, errorCode: 0, msg: , info: arrayOfDictValue([["name": "a"]]) - badStringConversion for understanding: [["name": "a"]]
```

Comment: Now i want to pass in info as a parameter just like  `public func Test(data: Data,info: InfoClass) {
        do {
            let json: BaseJsonResult<info> = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseJson<info>.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }` what should I do to install of info?

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you add more details?

Comment: I want to pass the info in BaseJson as a parameter. For example, I know the type of info. Now I want to pass this type to BaseJosn, just like if info is an Int, then pass Int, if it’s String, then pass String,if Is a dictionary, then I declare a dictionary type instead of info parsing .Like `let json: BaseJsonResult<Int:info> = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseJson<Int: Info>.self, from: data) `or `let json: BaseJsonResult<dictionary:info> = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseJson<dictionary:info>.self, from: data)  `

Comment: Why don't you let the `enum` decode itself? It will work for an Int/Dictionary. It works alone.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write it? thank you very much!!!

Comment: It's written there `info = try container.decode(Info.self, forKey: .info)`. So it's `let info = JSONDecoder().decode(Info.self, from data); switch info { case intValue(let itsAnInt): print(it'sAnInt); case ...  }`